# Should the title of an object type uinavigationitem be set in the viewcontroller or in the presenter in MVP architecture?

Tags: ios, mvp

I would like to know which component of the MVP architecture should know and set the title property of an object type of UINavigationItem class? Should it be the model, the presenter or the view (UIViewController) ?

Answer (score 0):

It’s Presenter’s responsibility. View should be as stupid(plain) as possible. I think it should look something like this:

```
protocol ViewInput {
    func setup(title: String)
}

protocol ViewOutput: AnyObject {
    func viewDidLoad()
}

class Presenter: ViewOutput {
    unowned var view: ViewOutput

    init(view: ViewOutput) {
        self.view = view
    }

    func viewDidLoad() {
       view.setup(title: "Your title")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, ViewInput {
    var presenter: ViewOutput?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       presenter.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func setup(title: String) {
       self.title = title
    }
}
```

If you write like this you can easily write unit tests for the view’s title. In a test you just put fake view in a presenter which implements ViewInput and can compare expected title and title that presenter setup.